# Do Questions about File Conversion via software available on Ubuntu Belong here in askubuntu?

Tags: discussion

Do Questions about File Conversion via software available on Ubuntu Belong here in askubuntu?

For further details the question I'm contemplating asking is about converting chm files to pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, questions about using Ubuntu to convert files from one format/encoding to another are on-topic for Ask Ubuntu.

Whether the software is available from Ubuntu's software sources, or must be obtained from unofficial sources (i.e., third party software), it is on topic. Please see [the FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions).

Of course, it's *possible* to ask a question about file conversion that is not good for Ask Ubuntu. For example, asking for a list of all file conversion software (for any format to any other format) is far too broad. If you're using an unsupported release of Ubuntu (like 11.04), that's considered off-topic.

But asking how to convert CHM files to PDF, with or without more details about your needs, is on topic. Of course:

- If you have detailed needs, please provide the details so you can get a good answer.
- As always, please search first, to see if your question has already been asked and answered.